# Map reduce to update a column on all rows

Tags: mapreduce

I've a table with 500M records. I need to update a column with some business logic. It is not a BULK update, its an individual update.

Was thinking to process/update 500M records, can MapReduce jobs efficient update the rows? My DB is MySQL.